# How can I use Powershell to list the names, last write date and file sizes on a disk SINCE YESTERDAY?

Tags: list, powershell, filenames, filesize

My incremental backup seemed to be backing up way to many MB's on an average day, so I was looking to verify that the files it backed up were in fact MODIFIED yesterday before the incremental.

I looked and looked for an answer to my question, didn't find one, so created the answer after a few hours of work borrowing heavily from all and sundry (thanks to all unnamed!) and thought I'd post the answer here for someone like me who just needs the answer and doesn't want to spend the hours I already spent.

Answer (score 1):

Results first - this is what the Powershell below yields:

```
FullName LastWriteDate Size (MB) -------- ------------- --------- 
F:\Shares\ComBackup\ComBackup_2020\MF1041520.ZIP 2020-04-15 320.35 
F:\Shares\ComBackup\ComBackup_2020\MF1141520.ZIP 2020-04-15 320.35 
F:\Shares\ComBackup\ComBackup_2020\MF241520.ZIP 2020-04-15 320.30 
F:\Shares\ComBackup\ComBackup_2020\MF341520.ZIP 2020-04-15 320.33 
F:\Shares\ComBackup\ComBackup_2020\MF41520.ZIP 2020-04-15 320.30 
F:\Shares\ComBackup\ComBackup_2020\MF441520.ZIP 2020-04-15 320.33 
F:\Shares\ComBackup\ComBackup_2020\MF541520.ZIP 2020-04-15 320.33 
F:\Shares\ComBackup\ComBackup_2020\MF641520.ZIP 2020-04-15 320.34
```

Code next

```
$yesterday = (get-date).date.adddays(-1) 
$today = (get-date).date 
Get-ChildItem -Recurse F: | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -ge $yesterday -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $today} | select Fullname, @{Name="LastWriteDate" Expression={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}}, @{ label='Size (MB)' expression={($_.Length/1MB).ToString('F2')}} | Format-Table -Autosize -Wrap
```